# User role and permissions for sending emails only in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, permissions, user-management, roles, email-studio

I have a task to create a user role in Marketing Cloud in which the user can create,read,edit and delete emails to already created audiences or data extensions .The user should only be able to select the names and not able to view any details inside it neither in audience builder nor in subscribers in email studio.Is there any way to implement this .Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure, if I have understood the question correctly. You wish to restrict the email permissions? Or do you wish to restrict the data extension permissions?

Comment: I wish to restrict the data extension permission so that all the email permissions are there .They can select the data extension name while sending but cant view the contents of it.@SwatiMishra

Comment: Can you try the Marketing Cloud Content Editor/Publisher role? I think it should work.

Comment: This role didn't work .Since the email studio content is locked and the content builder doesnnt function as email studio .Thank you

Comment: I have the opposite, I want to not allow user to send emails, any ideas on how to achive that ?